# PHP: Load similar results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search

I'm developing a car listing website, when a user vists the car description page on the sidebar I'd like to show similar results to the car shown based on this parameters:

- Make
- Model
- Year
- Price

---

Say you are seeing the page of a **Mini Cooper S 2014** that costs **$1,000 USD**, how can I show 5 similar results around this car? Maybe the another **Mini Cooper S 2014** but now another that costs **$800 USD** or another that costs **$1,100 USD** or different year.

Now if the possibilities described above (of showing same car but more options of it) don't exist, then show other cars around the same price of **+/- $500 USD**

How can I accomplish this with a Query or conditions? Thanks in advance and excuse my english

Comment: `SELECT * FROM CAR WHERE car_name LIKE %Mini Cooper%`, you will get all car with name `Mini Cooper`  and show them.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh thank you, what about the other conditions? now is not car_name one is **make**, other is **model**, other **year** and another is **price**

Comment: Use `Or` in between.

Comment: Your question is severely lacking information. I you don't define *similar results* and *options*. nobody can answer.

Comment: @JanDoggen I believe is perfectly described, after I say "similar results" on the first line I countinue describing what I mean with that. Read after the question mark on the second line please

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Order by`, `Like` and `Limit` in your SQL codes. Something like this:

// For Year

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where Year='$car' order by Year LIMIT 5;
```

// For Model

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where Model like '%$car%' LIMIT 5;
```

// For Price

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where Price='$car' order by Price LIMIT 5;
```

And so on for the rest ..!

---

**Edit**

For searching price of +/- $500 USD:

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename where Price between '+500' and '-500' order by Price LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thank you. One question, what if with the combination of the query, let's say from make, model and year it only returns 3 results. What can I do with the restant 2 results? How can I implement  searching now price of **+/- $500 USD**

Comment: Your welcome, And if you want to mix sql codes, you can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`